# Can I create a report with only summarized data?

Tags: reporting

My client currently has a report that they only want to see summaries of.  Currently we see:

[image]

But they only want to see the total number of records summarized and the Summarized Dollar amount.

I created a Formula in the Report to summarize the Amount data, but when I remove the Amount field the report disapears.  Any other ideas?

EDIT:  They want to be able to export the results.  The hide button doesn't work because when you export, it still grabs all the values.

Comment: there's always Conga Composer

Comment: @crop1645 Hmmm never heard of that.... but unfortunately isn't free. Might be useful down the road though or for other projects.

Comment: This product allows one to send from SFDC formatted excel output to your users via email on a schedule or on-demand via a click or via workflow; great tech support. well worth it

Answer (score 1):

On any report you should see a button to `Hide Details`. This should accomplish what you are looking for.

[image: Hide Details Button]

Comment: Close.  The only reason this doesn't work is because they want to export it it.  +1 anyways though.